# How to display more frequencies on the librosa spectogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, fft, librosa

I'm trying to plot 44.1 kHz audio spectrogram with log-scale. But librosa shows only **2^14** (16384) Hz, but it should be something between **2^15** and **2^16** Hz. How I can plot full-scale spectrogram?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import librosa


y, sr1 = librosa.load('sample01.wav', duration=10,sr=44100)

S = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(S,ref=np.max), y_axis='log',sr=sr1, x_axis='time', ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Log')
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: If the sample rate is 44.1 kHz then the Nyquist frequency is 22.05 kHz so you will only get meaningful data for frequencies below this (typically up to around 20 kHz).

Answer (score 0):

Librosa works correctly and shows frequencies up to fs/2. It is hard to see on log scale. You can either use zoom-in to top part and you will see that it gets to around 21.05kHz.

I modified your example, added below setting yticks, to prove those frequencies are there (and ofc had to make some random signal)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import librosa

y = np.random.randn(44100)
sr1 = 44100
S = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(S,ref=np.max), y_axis='log',sr=sr1, x_axis='time', ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Log')
ax.set_yticks([1,10,100,1000,10000,22000])
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, format="%+2.0f dB")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So, it's happening because of Nyquist frequency. But is there anyway to plot a full scale spectrogram, or it's way how STFT is works?

Comment: @Spetra what do you mean by "full scale spectrogram"? Fourier Transform (which is every column of the spectrogram) can't give you information about frequencies above Nyquist frequency.

Comment: @Speсtra, for the reason of Nyquist frequency, as dankal444 mentioned, you need make sure sample rate is at least twice as large as max frequency of the audio signal you are trying to display.